# Cannot debug a dll

Tags: dll

My main porject is an MFC application and another project which outputs a DLL. The main project is using this DLL.

The code runs perfectly fine, however, when I put a break point in the DLL code, the code does not stop at this break point when I run the code.

What changes do I need to make in the project?

Many thanks for your help.

Best Regards

Chintan

Answer (score 1):

The basic troubleshooter here is the Debug + Windows + Modules window.  First ensure that you see the DLL in the list of modules.  If you don't then the main EXE somehow didn't load the DLL and breakpoints will never work.  Next, pay attention to the Path of the DLL and make sure that it is the one that you just built and not some old copy.  Next, right-click the DLL and click "Symbol Load Information".  It shows you where it looked for the PDB, required by the debugger to figure out exactly where to set the breakpoint in the code.  Make sure it matches the PDB that was just created by the project.

Comment: OK. So from what can see in the output window, it shows the following: Loaded 'C:\DSP\NewComm.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.

Comment: I also checked this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/605a12zt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx but I cannot fidn step number 5 in my project. And ignoring this step, if I follow all teh steps, still I no effect.

Comment: The problem is solved.
 
Apparently, I had to enable Debug option, in the linker.
 
So Properties - Linker - Debugging - General Debug Info to YES.
 
Best Regards
 
Chintan